# ¿Como puedo cargar un archivo .jsp en Tomcat 8?

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, apache2, https

Mi sistema operativo es `Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS`, y he descargado la última versión de Tomcat, la 8.55. 
He configurado apache2 y Tomcat para que Tomcat se ejecute por https, sin embargo tengo un archivo en `/opt/tomcat/webapp/archivo.jsp` que cuando intento ejecutarlo en `https://localhost/webapp/archivo.jsp` no me carga y me devuelve un 404.

Answer (score 2):

No puedes cargar un archivo JSP suelto en un contenedor de aplicaciones, tienes que declarar una aplicación (con un archivo web.xml), exponiendo los Servlets que se van a ejecutar. Esto se suele empaquetar en un fichero war que es lo que se despliega en el servidor.

Comment: Hay alguna manera sin empaquetarlo en un fichero war? O hay herramientas que me permitan generarlo a partir de mi jsp?

Comment: lo más cómodo es crear un proyecto web en un IDE como eclipse o netbeans, crear el JSP y luego ejecutarlo desde el propio IDE

Comment: Estabas preguntando por herramientas para generarlo, también puedes crear el proyecto con Maven y luego usar `mvn install` para generar el war

Answer (score 0):

La solución más simple, es guardar el archivo prueba.jsp en el directorio 
/opt/tomcat/webapp/examples, tal y como muestra la imagen:https://i.stack.imgur.com/9MpT8.jpg